# Displaying content under a tab in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display a  report using Shiny dashboard under one of the tabs. How should I do that. 
please help me.
I am very new to R shiny!!

Thanks.

Comment: What is 'a report'? Do you have any code? Did you try anything already? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I want to display a summary of my Linear Model in Shiny @Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your UI function you can have a dashboard element inside which  you can have a dashboardBody.
In dashboardBody you will can have tabs like :

```
dashboardBody(
    fluidPage( 
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel('tab 1',
                     dataTableOutput('datatable')),
            tabPanel('tab 2', 
                     dataTableOutput('datatable5'))
          )
)
```

While in the server function you can create an output like:

```
output$datatable = renderDataTable(df1)
output$datatable5 = renderDataTable(df2)
```

where df1 and df2 are dataframes to be represented

Comment: @Manas Sonawane If the answer helps you. kindly accept it as a solution.